# Getting error with S3 bucket endpoint error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

My bucket is located at `us-west-2` and And file is properly uploading on `s3` But when I am trying to download it getting errors

```
<Error><Code>PermanentRedirect</Code>
      <Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message>                     
     <RequestId>2C53AD66AA6BE074</RequestId>
     <Bucket>mytprod</Bucket>
     <Endpoint>mytprod.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
</Error>
```

`production.rb`

```
 # Paperclip configuration
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => 'mytprod',
    :access_key_id => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    :secret_access_key => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    :region            => 'us-west-2',
    :s3_endpoint => "ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
    },
  }
```

Please help me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it's not liking: `ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` You can just try to use endpoint: `s3.amazonaws.com` like the message says.  According to the docs that's also an endpoint for the Pacific Northwest (us-west-2)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Answer (score 0):

ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com is *not* a valid S3 endpoint.

It looks like, coincidentally, Amazon has a *bucket* (of their own) called "ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" that exists for the purpose of redirecting curious people people seeing EC2 hostnames over to the EC2 landing page... so pretty much by luck, chance, and coincidence, the request happens to be hitting S3, which is generating the redirect.

"s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com" is the correct endpoint for S3 in us-west-2.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

The explanation for why the upload isn't also broken is -- most likely -- because the library you are using is handling the redirect message in the background and resending the request to the correct place.